# Python Simon Game: I Cannot Make the Command of the Button Work the Way I Need

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Simon Game in Python using Tkinter and I am having problems making work the command of the button.

For the game the activebackground of the button must change from the normal color to another color when clicked and then return to the normal color and I must be able to repeat the action for an indefinite amount of clicks.

The necessary code for this is:

```
import Tkinter

base = Tkinter.Tk()

fr = Tkinter.Frame(base, bg="black", width="238", height="238")

def yellowClick():

    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow3")

yellow = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                    width="7", height="5", activebackground="yellow",  
                    bg="yellow3", command = yellowClick)

yellow.place(x = 30, y = 30)

fr.pack()

base.mainloop()
```

Here the actual code in the yellowClick() function makes the activebackground of the button to properly change color to yellow3, but I don't know how to return it after 3 seconds to yellow, and then be able to repeat the action for an indefinite amount of clicks.

I tried with time.sleep() in this way:

```
def yellowClick():

    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow3")

    time.sleep(3)

    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow")
```

But it only makes the button to turn yellow and last 3 seconds. Instead of turning yellow3, wait 3 seconds and then return to yellow.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't know how to return it after 3 seconds to yellow,

Tkinter widgets have a method named `after` for precisely this sort of thing. If you want to change it to a different color in three seconds you can do this:

```
 yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow3")
 yellow.after(3000, lambda: yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow"))
```

This creates an anonymous function that will run approximately three seconds (3000 milliseconds) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Tkinter
import time

base = Tkinter.Tk()
fr = Tkinter.Frame(base, bg="black", width="238", height="238")

def yellowClick():
    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow")
    time.sleep(3)
    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow3")

yellow = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                    width="7", height="5", activebackground="yellow",
                    bg="yellow3", command = yellowClick)

yellow.place(x = 30, y = 30)
fr.pack()
base.mainloop()
```

This works for me. What's the result on your machine?

Comment: For me this works upside down, because it makes the color order to be yellow during 3 seconds and then yellow3, it must from yellow turn yellow3 and then yellow.

Comment: I moved that `3` 2 lines down :)

Comment: If you mean between both yellow.configure, thats what i've tried.

Comment: that `time.sleep(3)` will prevent you from seeing the results of the `configure` immediately before it.

Comment: So it covers the first configure?

Comment: If you want yellow -> yellow3 -> yellow then just switch everything the other way around.

Comment: Or maybe is my computer, because switching them make the yellow last more and then the click turns off.

Comment: Do you know another way I could do it?

Comment: Look at @BryanOakley answer.